# SonarQube 6.7.3 widget disable

Tags: sonarqube

I'm currently using SonarQube 6.7.3 for code analysis, I just wanted to disable vulnerability widget in the dashboard, I tried to disable the same but I could not. Kindly help me with the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to customize project's dashboard, but you can update the quality gate to not be red on security issues (even if it's not recommended to do that !).

Comment: thanks you!, I just tried to disable the rules itself